Backup files not saved with original user
I'm using rdiff-backup to backup from local filesystems to a remote Hetzner server with a mounted remote storage box. The storage box is mounted on the remote server as a cifs filesystem. The backup is run locally as root and the ssh connection to the remote server is also on root account. The problem I have is that the original files owner/group are not preserved. Everything gets owned by root.
This is how the storage box is mounted in /etc/fstab:
//user.your-storagebox.de/backup /storagebox cifs iocharset=utf8,rw,credentials=/etc/backup-credentials.txt,seal,uid=0,gid=0,file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0770 0 0

And the local command to backup:
rdiff-backup -v4 --api-version 201 backup --print-statistics \
    --include /home/cpn/Documents \
    --include /home/cpn/ProgramasRFB \
    --include /home/cpn/Pictures \
    --include /home/cpn/Videos \
    --include /hd2t/Fotos \
    --include /hd2t/Videos \
    --include /etc \
    --exclude '**' \
    / root@example.com::/storagebox/Backup/ & disown;

In instead of the files/directories be owned by the original user they all get owned by root in the storage box:
# ll
total 0
drwxrwx---. 2 root root 0 May 14 16:58 Documents
drwxrwx---. 2 root root 0 May  1 09:23 Pictures

What am I missing? My guess is that the problem is related to cifs
These are the only accesses offered by Hetzner for that cloud device: https://docs.hetzner.com/robot/storage-box/access/access-overview
I also tried SFTP with worse results

Well, you are mounting with uid=0,gid=0. What OS is the target system? If it's different than the source (e.g. syncing from Linux to Windows), how are you expecting it to know what user to use? Are they both using AD for their user/group directory? If not, there is no one-to-one mapping.

Are you backing up to Linux system? Why ever using CIFS there, which is foreign, and one of the most expected things about being foreign is that it will lose Linux attributes that differ the most between systems, like UID, GID, modes, POSIX ACL and xattrs?

@jpiddle888 strictly speaking, ntfs-3g drive does provide the UID mapping feature, but I rather say that it is thing which is just fun to play with and then give up with the filesystem. There is no valid reason to use CIFS in Linux on the device which is connected to that Linux forever and only to that Linux, and will never ever be connected to Windows. This is offtopic, since this site is about reasonable management practices.

@NikitaKipriyanov CIFS is one of the few access modes offered by Hetzner for that device: https://docs.hetzner.com/robot/storage-box/access/access-overview I also tried SFTP with worse results.

@jpiddle888 Source and target are Linux. The cloud target device is of unknown nature. I only know that if I connect to it over ssh I get a very basic shell: https://docs.hetzner.com/robot/storage-box/access/access-ssh-rsync-borg

Sorry, It was not clear to me that you're using a Hetzner Storage Box service and not renting some server where some storage box is connected. Still not sure why CIFS, when rsync @ SSH is available...

Such service probably won't let you store any file attributes that easily. On the storage system you're a low-privileged user, who is not permitted to use chown, so UIDs/GIDs can not be stored for sure, no matter how you access it. Simply said, the service doesn't implement enough POSIX semantics to store them.
I think, the idea behind Storage Box was to facilitate some space where users will put archives (tarballs) that contain all the metadata, for example, .tar.zst, or squashfs-compressed images that you can mount directly if you want to. It wouldn't matter who would be seen as the owner of the tarball itself.
What you can try:

Use a full blown backup system instead of rdiff-backup, like Amanda or BareOS, which can store its volumes on the Storage Box provided space. All the metadata will be encapsulated within volumes and it doesn't matter who owns volume files themselves.
Use some virtual file system that can store data on Storage Box and store POSIX attributes as a sidecar file, similar to how fuse_xattrs stores xattrs. It is not too hard to implement it yourself using e.g. fuse-python, the performance wouldn't be very high, but considering it's already over SSH to some remote, that would be negligible. Browse this, maybe, you'll find something that suits you. There's a ton of garbage, but gems appear too.


Thank you. I tried Borg and it works well for me.
